# How to add two input accessoryView for UITextView in iOS?

Tags: ios, custom-controls, uitextview

I need to add two input AccessoryView into my `UITextView`.

First i need to add custom control from [this link.](http://code4app.net/ios/Custom-Keyboard/504eaa926803fa347d000000)

That custom control use

```
[KOKeyboardRow applyToTextView:self.txtView];
```

So when i add my custom `accessoryView` to my `UITextView`,only custom control is showing and mine are not displaying.

Here is code that my custom `inputAccessoryView`.

```
self.txtView.inputAccessoryView = self.keyboardAccessoryView;
```

So how can i add two `inputAccessoryView` into `UITextView`?

Answer (score 3):

The `inputAccessoryView` is a single view. You need to create a single view (either a container or subclassing the 3rd party view) and add all of your content (buttons) to it.

---

Look at subclassing `KOKeyboardRow` just to expand the view that it uses as the `inputAccessoryView` and add your buttons to it. To do this cleanly you should change the public interface so that it takes a number of buttons (an `NSArray` property) as additional buttons that would be added below the standard buttons that it adds.

Comment: Yes , first i got a idea like you said. But that KOKeyboardRow use delegate of UITextView with applyToTextView.I have no idea how to combine these two accessoryView.

Answer (score 2):

wrap the two views in one custom `uiview`